# On Key Up vs On Change with AJAX queries: which is better?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm sending POST data from text boxes to a PHP page for processing. Rather than the user clicking a save button, AJAX is used on text box events.

I'm torn between using `onChange` or `onKeyUp`.

`OnKeyUp` requires more processing on server, because for every key press my script has to access the database and make the change. Server performance could be an issue.

`OnChange` is preferred, as it only sends the changes when the user has finished on the box. However, there is a problem that if the use does not deselect the text box, the event `onChange` doesn't happen, so changes aren't saved.

Which would be best? Or is there a way to enforce `onChange` without the user deselecting the box?

Comment: Well you could use http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ which is similar to onKeyUp but it is prefferd for user input. What if you wold make the change when user stops tiping for lets say two seconds?

Comment: Good idea. I'll try the time delay. I'd love to use jQuery but can't as it's for a college project

Comment: @DanielOakey: Please check below ans, see if that work for you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even use the KeyUp press ajax call, how??
Just add the delayKeyUp function on keyUp event, and delayKeyUp function has setTimeout method, this would really help you out as per as server processing concern,

**Note:** This works fine for one method at a time.

Ex. Code:

**Update:**

```
$("selector").live('keyup', function(e) { //if jquery v1.7 or more then you can use .on event instead of .live
    delayKeyUp(function(){ ---Your Server Call Stuff -----}, 350); //delay of 350ms.
    return false;
});


var delayKeyUp = (function(){
     var timer = 0;
     return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
     };
})();
```

Comment: This won't work for more than one ajax query though will it? ie `delayKeyUp(foo, 100); delayKeyUp(bar, 200);` They will both share the same 'timer' object, and cause problems for eachother

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated as of jQ 1.7, and should be replaced with `.on()` - http://api.jquery.com/live/ - Also @AlanFoster this will work with multiple calls, due to something called closures - trying to understand these will make your head hurt, so it's probably best to prove it to yourself by trying it, and leave it at that for now :P They're important to understand though, so do have a look into them at some point

Comment: @Joe I'm saying this won't work /because/ of closures haha. Since one function object is returned, and it still has access to the single outter timer object, it means it'll cause problems... Right? :o

Comment: @AlanFoster: This works fine for one server call at a time, Ofcourse, it Needed some work to make it happen for more than one server call too.

Comment: @Niks Post a solution that will work for numerous callbacks and I'll give you my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

In what scenario would the user not blur the textbox, resulting in the AJAX not happening?

One possible solution is to set a timeout to keyDown and keyUp so that after a certain period of no typing, the AJAX will fire, something along these lines. This probably has a bug in that it may not update the textbox if you start typing in another one before that textbox's `$.ajax` has run, but you should be able to get the idea

```
var key_is_down = false,
    key_timeout;

$(el).on('keyDown', function () {
    key_is_down = true;
}).on('keyUp', function () {
    key_is_down = false;
    key_timeout = setTimeout(function(){ runAjax($(this)); }, 2500);
});

function runAjax ($el) {
    if (key_is_down) {
        key_timeout = setTimeout(function(){ runAjax($el); }, 2500);
    } else {
        // $.ajax...
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also just seen your comment against the OP about not being able to use jQ - remember that jQ is just Javascript, nicely packaged. If you're not able to use jQ, you can probably just go nick `.on()` from the source, and re-define it as a function you can use :P Obviously `$()` just becomes `document.getElementById()`

Comment: They wouldn't blur the text box if it was the last edit they made. For example: they make changes, then close the page. The last text box was still focused as they quit, so wasn't saved.

Comment: So an alternative solution is to bind `$('input:focus').trigger('change')` to `window.onbeforeunload` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.page_loaded = new Date();
$('text_field').bind('keyup', function(){
    var timeout_seconds = 10;

    var last_check = $(this).data('last_checked');
    last_check = last_check ? last_check : window.page_loaded;
    var curr_time = new Date();
    curr_time = new Date(curr_time.getTime() - (timeout_seconds * 1000));
    if(last_check < curr_time){
        //now do the checking
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't we take here help of closures method, instead of doing some rough method to make it happen?? :)

Comment: @Niks : Does this makes any sense to use closures?? Not a rough method dude, the user wants some timeout for interacting with the server , and thats what my code does. :)

Comment: See above answers and observe it, which looks more professional & generic.

Comment: @Niks : Prof???? One is using depriciated func and other is setting just timeout but all calls will be sent to server on each keyup after the timeout!!!!!