# SlickGrid filtering on multiple columns (with JSFiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slickgrid, jsfiddle

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/freva/sQXAt/6/)
, I have a SlickGrid witch get filled with Ajax and I can search in one column. This is all explained well in an [example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html) of SlickGrid. Now I would like to make a custom filter. This filter is a text field and can search in multiple columns. (all columns actually)
With the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463285/slickgrid-searching-multiple-column).
This is the code I have:

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

    $('#txtSearch').keyup(function (e) {
        var searchList = $.trim(this.value.toLowerCase()).split(' ');
        dataView.setFilter(gridFilter);
        grid.invalidate();
        this.focus();
    });

    function gridFilter(rec) {
        var found;
        for (i = 0; i < gridSearchList.length; i += 1) {
            found = false;
            $.each(rec, function (obj, objValue) {
                if (typeof objValue !== 'undefined' && objValue != null
                && objValue.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(gridSearchList[i]) != -1) {
                    found = true;
                    return false; //this breaks the $.each loop
                }
            });
            if (!found) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Currently I'm getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label '_coreloop'" in the slick.dataview.js file when I try to do the .setFilter(). What could be wrong with the code? Variable gridSearchList is the data(array) I got from Ajax.
Thanks!

Comment: hmmm it appears the fiddle doesn't seem to find myGrid. This is not the issue I got in my solution. I'm investigating this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter code doesn't seem compatible with SlickGrid's filter inlining.  Turn it off in the DataView.